# Printer driver for HP

Tags: 16.04, drivers, printing

Ubunutu 16.04 LTS

Ubuntu does not detect `HP Color Laserjet Flow MFP M880` in Printers configuration

I used `hp-setup` but no such device in the list.

Looks like driver is missing

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: It appears on my 16.10 system. Have you installed `hplip`? Which version? `sudo dpkg -s hplip` I have version 3.16.7+repack0-1ubuntu1.

Answer (score 0):

HP have a trouble-shooting area on their hplip site

http://hplipopensource.com/node/332

they suggest `hp-check`

hplip says it only needs 3.13 version and no plug-in needed: current ubuntu has 3.16.3 of hplip